# Event triggers for animations using vanilla ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, dom, animation

I'm new to JS and wanna know right code style or approach to cod Vanilla JS using ES6. To practice this, I'm using ESLint JS code-style of AirBnb and referencing [clean-code-javascript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript) repo. However, I cannot sure it is right style for me because I'm newbie. For this reason, I want to ask code review about my simple Vanilla JS.

> **What I'm doing.**
>
> 1. Activate hover on/off events to 2 elements because it cannot be
>      implemented by CSS now.
> 2. Activate click event to 2 elements for
>      animation.
> 3. Activate no-rebuild event to window to prevent
>      rebuilding of animation.

My files are [`photo.js`](https://github.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/blob/fca2848ce5f8518540c6265a9e7e1ab956d9254f/js/photo.js), [`photo.css`](https://github.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/blob/fca2848ce5f8518540c6265a9e7e1ab956d9254f/css/photo.css), and [`photo.html`](https://github.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/blob/fca2848ce5f8518540c6265a9e7e1ab956d9254f/html/photo.html).

```js
const initializeAnimation = function initializeAnimation() {
  const swiperImgs = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper__img');
  const swiperTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper__title');
  const swiperImgLefts = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper__img__left');
  const swiperImgRights = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper__img__right');
  const swiperContentsInsides = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper__contents__inside');
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

  const addHoverOnEventToImg = function addHoverOnEventToImg() {
    swiperImgs.forEach((swiperImg, index) => swiperImg.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      swiperImg.classList.add('hover-up');
      swiperTitles[index].classList.add('hover-up');
      swiperImgLefts[index].classList.add('hover-hide');
      swiperImgRights[index].classList.add('hover-hide');
    }));
  };

  const addHoverOnEventToTItle = function addHoverOnEventToTItle() {
    swiperTitles.forEach((swiperTitle, index) => swiperTitle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      swiperTitle.classList.add('hover-up');
      swiperImgs[index].classList.add('hover-up');
      swiperImgLefts[index].classList.add('hover-hide');
      swiperImgRights[index].classList.add('hover-hide');
    }));
  };

  const addHoverOffEventToImg = function addHoverOffEventToImg() {
    swiperImgs.forEach((swiperImg, index) => swiperImg.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      swiperImg.classList.remove('hover-up');
      swiperTitles[index].classList.remove('hover-up');
      swiperImgLefts[index].classList.remove('hover-hide');
      swiperImgRights[index].classList.remove('hover-hide');
    }));
  };

  const addHoverOffEventToTitle = function addHoverOffEventToTitle() {
    swiperTitles.forEach((swiperTitle, index) => swiperTitle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      swiperTitle.classList.remove('hover-up');
      swiperImgs[index].classList.remove('hover-up');
      swiperImgLefts[index].classList.remove('hover-hide');
      swiperImgRights[index].classList.remove('hover-hide');
    }));
  };

  const addClickEventToImg = () => {
    swiperImgs.forEach((swiperImg, index) => swiperImg.addEventListener('click', () => {
      swiperImgLefts[index].classList.add('left-gone');
      swiperImgRights[index].classList.add('right-gone');
      swiperTitles[index].classList.add('move-up');
      swiperImg.classList.add('move-down');
      sections.forEach((section, sectionIndex) => {
        if (sectionIndex !== index) {
          section.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
      swiperContentsInsides[index].classList.add('appear');
      fullpage_api.destroy();
    }));
  };

  const addNoRebuildEvent = () => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      if (matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) {
        const moveDownElem = document.querySelector('.move-down');
        // moveDownElem.classList.remove('move-down');
        moveDownElem.classList.add('no-rebuild');
      }
    });
  };

  addHoverOnEventToImg();
  addHoverOnEventToTItle();
  addHoverOffEventToImg();
  addHoverOffEventToTitle();
  addClickEventToImg();
  addNoRebuildEvent();
};

const initializeFullpage = function initializeFullpage() {
  new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    autoScrolling: true,
    licenseKey: '00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000'
  });
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
};

window.onload = () => {
  initializeAnimation();
  initializeFullpage();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #031f1c;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.swiper {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__img__inside {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 150%;
}

.swiper__contents__main,
.swiper__img__left,
.swiper__img__right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper__contents__main {
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.swiper__img__left {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.swiper__img__right {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.irene__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene1.jpg'); }
.irene__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene2.jpg'); }
.irene__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene3.jpg'); }
.seulgi__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-seulgi1.jpg'); }
.seulgi__right { background-image: url('../images/photo-seulgi2.jpg'); }
.seulgi__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-seulgi3.jpg'); }
.wendy__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy1.jpg'); }
.wendy__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy2.jpg'); }
.wendy__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy3.jpg'); }
.yeri__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri1.jpg'); }
.yeri__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri2.jpg'); }
.yeri__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri3.jpg'); }
.joy__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy1.jpg'); }
.joy__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy2.jpg'); }
.joy__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy3.jpg'); }

.swiper__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__title h2 {
  font-size: 20rem;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Libre Caslon Display', serif;
}

.swiper__contents {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.swiper__contents__inside {
  display: none;
}

.swiper__contents__component {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
}

.hover-up { top: 45%; }
.hover-hide { opacity: 0.7; }
.move-up { animation: moveUp 1.5s both 0.5s; }
.left-rotate { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-50%); }
.right-rotate { transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(50%); }
.left-gone { animation: leftGone 1s both; }
.right-gone { animation: rightGone 1s both; }
.move-down { animation: moveDown 1.5s both 0.5s; }
.hide { animation: hide 1s both 0.5s; }

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  animation: show 0s both 1s;
}

/* TODO !important가 좋은 해결방법인가? */
.no-rebuild {
  animation-duration: 0s !important;
  animation-delay: 0s !important;
}

@keyframes leftGone {
  from { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-50%); }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rightGone {
  from { transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(50%); }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes moveUp {
  from { top: 50%; }
  to { top: 5%; }
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  from {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  to {
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width: 80vw;
  }
}

@keyframes moveDownMobile {
  from {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  to {
    top: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width: 80vw;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from { top: 200%; }
  to { top: 100%; }
}

@keyframes hide {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Media Query */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .swiper__title h2 {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }

  .move-down {
    animation: moveDownMobile 1.5s both 0.5s;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="https://raw.githack.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/html/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Caslon+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fullpage.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css">
  <title>Photo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header-js" class="header">
    <div class="header__inside clearfix">
      <a href="./index.html">
        <img class="header__logo" src="../images/logo-red.png" alt="로고">
      </a>
      <div id="header__menu-js" class="header__menu">
        <input type="checkbox" id="menuicon">
          <label for="menuicon">
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>홈</h1>
  </header>
  <aside id="overlay-js" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="overlay__closeBtn-js" class="overlay__closeBtn">&times;</a>
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="./about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="./photo.html">PHOTOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="./discography.html">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a href="./video.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <main id="fullpage">
    <section id="irene" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#031F1C">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left irene__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right irene__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main irene__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene4.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene5.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene6.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene7.jpg" alt="아이린">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>IRENE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="seulgi" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#1f1b11">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left seulgi__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right seulgi__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main seulgi__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi4.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi5.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi6.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi7.jpg" alt="슬기">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>SEULGI</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="wendy" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#291310">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left wendy__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right wendy__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main wendy__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy4.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy5.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy6.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy7.jpg" alt="웬디">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>WENDY</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="yeri" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#5e0238">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left yeri__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right yeri__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main yeri__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri4.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri5.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri6.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri7.jpg" alt="예리">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>YERI</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="joy" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#4e087c">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left joy__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right joy__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main joy__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy4.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy5.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy6.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy7.jpg" alt="조이">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>JOY</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="../js/fullpage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/intersection-observer.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/default.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @200_success I added CSS and HTML codes.

Comment: That constructor is in external file named `fullpage.min.js`. It is package.

Comment: Umm.. I just wanna good code-style, do I have to include real stuffs?

Comment: Code Review requires real working code — see the [help/on-topic]. Excerpts are acceptable, but you should include enough code so that your question makes sense.

Comment: Okay, I modified js files to link files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Styling

Consider using [`-webkit-text-stroke`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke) to make the `<h2>` text legible even when superimposed on a white image.

### Trivial errors

`addHoverOnEventToTItle()` has improper capitalization.

The image click handler calls `swiperContentsInsides[index].classList.add('appear')`, but the CSS has no rule for `.appear`.  Did you mean `show` instead of `appear`?

### Technique

**You aren't using CSS effectively, which forces you to abuse JavaScript to achieve your goals.**  Instead, you should write just enough JavaScript to mark strategically chosen elements to be in a certain mode, then let the CSS cascade take care of the rest.

Specifically, your `addHoverOnEventToImg()`, `addHoverOnEventToTItle()`, `addHoverOffEventToImg()`, and `addHoverOffEventToTitle()` can all be replaced by a simple handler that adds or removes a `hover` class from a `section`.  Then, the CSS rules should instruct the elements within the affected section to behave accordingly.  Instead of:

> ```
> .hover-up { top: 45%; }
> .hover-hide { opacity: 0.7; }
> ```

… you should write:

```
section.hover .swiper__img,
section.hover .swiper__title {
  top: 45%;
}

section.hover .swiper__img__left,
section.hover .swiper__img__right {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

The `addNoRebuildEvent()` function can be replaced entirely with CSS.

For a more powerful demonstration of this technique, see [iPhone notes application replica using HTML/CSS](/a/77162/9357).

```js
const initializeAnimation = function initializeAnimation() {
  document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach((section) => {
    const mouseenterHandler = () => { section.classList.add('hover'); };
    const mouseleaveHandler = () => { section.classList.remove('hover'); };
    const imgclickHandler = () => {
      section.classList.add('single');
      document.querySelectorAll('section').forEach((s) => {
        if (s != section) {
          s.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
      fullpage_api.destroy();
    };

    section.querySelectorAll('.swiper__title, .swiper__img, .swiper__img__left, .swiper__img__right').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenterHandler);
      el.addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleaveHandler);
    });
    section.querySelectorAll('.swiper__img').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', imgclickHandler);
    });
  });
};

const initializeFullpage = function initializeFullpage() {
  new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    autoScrolling: true,
    licenseKey: '00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000'
  });
  fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(true);
};

window.onload = () => {
  initializeAnimation();
  initializeFullpage();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #031f1c;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.swiper {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 40rem;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__img__inside {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 150%;
}

.swiper__contents__main,
.swiper__img__left,
.swiper__img__right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.swiper__contents__main {
  z-index: 1;
}

.swiper__contents__main,
.swiper__img__left,
.swiper__img__right {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.irene__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene1.jpg'); }
.irene__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene2.jpg'); }
.irene__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-irene3.jpg'); }
.seulgi__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-seulgi1.jpg'); }
.seulgi__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-seulgi2.jpg'); }
.seulgi__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-seulgi3.jpg'); }
.wendy__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy1.jpg'); }
.wendy__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy2.jpg'); }
.wendy__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-wendy3.jpg'); }
.yeri__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri1.jpg'); }
.yeri__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri2.jpg'); }
.yeri__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-yeri3.jpg'); }
.joy__left { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy1.jpg'); }
.joy__right { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy2.jpg'); }
.joy__main { background-image: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/images/photo-joy3.jpg'); }

.swiper__title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__title h2 {
  font-size: 20rem;
  color: white;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
  font-family: 'Libre Caslon Display', serif;
}

.swiper__contents {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.swiper__contents__inside {
  display: none;
}

.swiper__contents__component {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
}

section.hover .swiper__img,
section.hover .swiper__title {
  top: 45%;
}

section.hover .swiper__img__left,
section.hover .swiper__img__right {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

section.single .swiper__title {
  animation: moveUp 1.5s both 0.5s;
}
section.single .swiper__img {
  animation: moveDown 1.5s both 0.5s;
}
section.single .swiper__img__left {
  animation: leftGone 1s both;
}
section.single .swiper__img__right {
  animation: rightGone 1s both;
}
.left-rotate { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-50%); }
.right-rotate { transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(50%); }
.hide { animation: hide 1s both 0.5s; }

.show {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  animation: show 0s both 1s;
}

@keyframes leftGone {
  from { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(-50%); }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rightGone {
  from { transform: rotate(5deg) translateX(50%); }

  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes moveUp {
  from { top: 50%; }
  to { top: 5%; }
}

@keyframes moveDown {
  from {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  to {
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width: 80vw;
  }
}

@keyframes moveDownMobile {
  from {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  to {
    top: 20%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    width: 80vw;
  }
}

@keyframes show {
  from { top: 200%; }
  to { top: 100%; }
}

@keyframes hide {
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}

/* Media Query */

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .swiper__title h2 {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }

  .move-down {
    animation: moveDownMobile 1.5s both 0.5s;
  }

  /* TODO !important가 좋은 해결방법인가? */
  section.single .swiper__img {
    animation-duration: 0s !important;
    animation-delay: 0s !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="https://raw.githack.com/baeharam/Redvelvet-Fansite/master/html/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Caslon+Display&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fullpage.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/default.css">
  <title>Photo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header id="header-js" class="header">
    <div class="header__inside clearfix">
      <a href="./index.html">
        <img class="header__logo" src="../images/logo-red.png" alt="로고">
      </a>
      <div id="header__menu-js" class="header__menu">
        <input type="checkbox" id="menuicon">
          <label for="menuicon">
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
            <span class="menu-light"></span>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>홈</h1>
  </header>
  <aside id="overlay-js" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="overlay__closeBtn-js" class="overlay__closeBtn">&times;</a>
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="./about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="./photo.html">PHOTOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="./discography.html">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a href="./video.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
  <main id="fullpage">
    <section id="irene" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#031F1C">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left irene__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right irene__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main irene__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene4.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene5.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene6.jpg" alt="아이린">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-irene7.jpg" alt="아이린">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>IRENE</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="seulgi" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#1f1b11">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left seulgi__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right seulgi__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main seulgi__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi4.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi5.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi6.jpg" alt="슬기">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-seulgi7.jpg" alt="슬기">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>SEULGI</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="wendy" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#291310">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left wendy__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right wendy__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main wendy__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy4.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy5.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy6.jpg" alt="웬디">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-wendy7.jpg" alt="웬디">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>WENDY</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="yeri" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#5e0238">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left yeri__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right yeri__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main yeri__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri4.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri5.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri6.jpg" alt="예리">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-yeri7.jpg" alt="예리">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>YERI</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="joy" class="section">
      <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper__img" data-color="#4e087c">
          <div class="swiper__img__inside">
            <div class="swiper__img__left joy__left"></div>
            <div class="swiper__img__right joy__right"></div>
            <div class="swiper__contents">
              <div class="swiper__contents__main joy__main"></div>
              <div class="swiper__contents__inside">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy4.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy5.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy6.jpg" alt="조이">
                <img class="swiper__contents__component" src="../images/photo-joy7.jpg" alt="조이">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper__title">
          <h2>JOY</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="../js/fullpage.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/intersection-observer.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/default.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try and ask if I don't understand.